# How to unmarshal Ruby object with PHP

Tags: php, ruby, marshalling

Marshaled data is in redis server and I need to access it with PHP. No other options.

Comment: How does the marshalled data look like? Is it a common format like YAML or JSON?

Comment: And how are you going to load, serialized by ruby, object with php?

Comment: It is a string. Data looks like "I"Denmark:ET" I copied it form Redis Desktop manager.

Comment: You'll not get far unless you know the format of the data, is it, in Ruby `Marshal.dump("thing")`?

Comment: @Kris, yes they are using ruby's Marshal.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest writing Ruby to `Marshal.load` the data in to Ruby objects and then dumping it back as JSON or YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no deserializer for Ruby's internal Marshal format for PHP. You can write one, of course, [here's the documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/marshal.rdoc).

Also, it simply might not be possible to represent the Ruby object as a PHP object, if the Ruby object uses features that PHP lacks. Either way, you will probably have to re-implement significant portions of Ruby's object model in PHP, in order to deserialize a Ruby Marshal string. For example, what if, after decoding the string, you end up with an object which is an instance of `UserFoo` with 3 instance variables referencing instances of class `MyBar`?

Anyway, here is a series of blog posts to get you started:

1. [A little dip into Ruby's Marshal format](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2013/01/15/a-little-dip-into-rubys-marshal-format/)
2. [Another dip into Ruby's Marshal format](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2013/01/16/another-dip-into-rubys-marshal-format/)
3. [A final dip into Ruby's Marshal format](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2013/01/20/a-final-dip-into-rubys-marshal-format/)

One thing you *could* try, is to run your PHP code on the JVM using one of the existing JVM implementations of PHP (e.g. Quercus or P8) and [embed an instance of JRuby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1765060/2988) in your app to deserialize the string, provided the string can be deserialized with JRuby. (Similarly, you could do the same with IronPHP and IronRuby on the CLI.)

Comment: [It's documented](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/marshal.rdoc). Did you just not know or don't you consider it well documented?

Comment: Indeed, I did not know that! Note that that document is just over two years old, whereas Ruby itself is well over 22 years old, so for over 20 years, the Marshal format indeed *was* undocumented (and for example JRuby, XRuby, Ruby.NET, IronRuby, Rubinius, SmallRuby, Topaz, Cardinal, BlueRuby, IoRuby, Red Sun, RubyGoLightly, tinyrb, … all had to reverse-engineer MRI/YARV over and over and over and over again). Anyway, my bad, it's been over two years since I last checked, and I should have checked again to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another format (that easier because you don't need to write your own unmarshal library) instead of ruby internal marshalling, something like JSON, XML etc.

Or you can simple execute ruby script from php which unmarshal ruby object.